# fetch data from array response

Tags: php, arrays, object

I've response as below.

```
array:4 [▼
   "response-1" => Data {#280 ▶}
   "response-2" => Exception {#235 ▼
                     #errors: array:1 [▶]
                       #message: "{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"User does not have sufficient permissions for this data."}],"code":403,"message":"User does not have sufficient permissions for this data."}}"
   "response-3" => Data {#280 ▶}
   "response-4" => Data {#280 ▶}
]
```

Now, I need to fetch only `Data` part leaving the `Exception` part untouched from response in PHP. I don't really know how to get through it but I did try something like this:

```
if(!$results['response-'. $id] == 'Exception'){
      //do something
}
```

Comment: So `Data` is a key that points to some other object or array? And you want to extract all of those?

Comment: Did you give up or what???

Answer (score 1):

Since the array is made up of other arrays, the simplest approach is to just iterate over each element in the array and extract the values in the `Data` key of each element.

This assumes that your array looks something like this:

```
$arr = [
    "response-1" => ["Data" => ["some other array or object here"]],
    "response-2" => ["Exception" => ["some other array or object here"]],
    "response-3" => ["Data" => ["some other array or object here"]],
    "response-4" => ["Data" => ["some other array or object here"]],
];
```

Then getting all the `Data` parts would look something like this...

```
foreach($arr as $part) {
    if (isset($part["Data"])) {
        // Do something with $part["Data"] here
        var_dump($part["Data"]); // e.g.
    }
}
```

## output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(31) "some other array or object here"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(31) "some other array or object here"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(31) "some other array or object here"
}
```

Comment: the array you used isn't same like the response I get. Response isn't array containing other arrays. I did try though, it throws error: "Cannot use object of type Exception as array"

Comment: Notice the `"some other array or object here"` part. Specifically the ***or object*** part. I was trying to be as generic as possible considering you make no actual distinction in your question. Obviously you don't use the same syntax to access object properties as you would arrays. Do [consult the manual for specific language syntax references](http://php.net/oop5).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get all of the `Data` values into an array:

```
$data = array_column($results, 'Data');
```

If those are actually objects, then:

```
$data = array_map(function($v) { return $v->Data; }, $results);
```